# Dealing with imports on sub-modules in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-module

I have the following structure

```
|-- package/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module.py
|   |-- subpackage/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- sub_module.py
```

My sub_module.py has one method definition, for example:

**sub_module.py**

```
def my_sub_method():
```

And my module.py have a lot of classes.
**module.py**

```
class Class1():
class Class2():
class Class3():
class Class4():
```

It this possible to do the following import?

**sub_module.py**

```
from package.module import Class1
```

And on main module

**module.py**

```
from subpackage.sub_module import my_sub_method
```

I tried do this import but didn't worked. I'm wondering if the problem is the circular module import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at this stackoverflow post?

[Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

This describes an array of ways to accomplish what I believe you are looking for.

HTHs

Thanks,

//P